# Compress image of any format(jpeg,png etc) in Asp.net with c# without effecting height & width?

Tags: c#, asp.net, image, image-processing

I have gone through many websites but those code are not working as expected. Some reduced the dimensions & some increases the image size.

Comment: What do you mean as "any extension"? I think it depends on the format of your image. Some formats are compressed already (jpeg, e.g) and you can't compress it without losing quality or size. So you won't get some universal solution.

Comment: Thanks, I Updated my question. I used third party tools and image size did not get effected and is reduced perfectly. http://www.dotnethelpers.com/Ultimate_Image_Resizer